Kmp Kotlin 2.0 with Ksp Koin Annotations doesn't find generated modules on iOS
After migration Kmp project from Kotlin 1.9.24 to 2.0.0 and updating ksp from 1.9.24-1.0.20 to 2.0.0-1.0.24, Android build works but iOS doesn't compile because it can't find generated Koin modules... the same error exists for all ksp 2.0.0-1.0.2* versions.
when revert to Kotlin 1.9.24 and ksp 1.9.24-1.0.20, both Android and iOS compile fine
any ideas what it could be?
to me it looks like somehow on iOS source sets do not include koin generated files but I don't have any specific setup for that, before the upgrade it used to work with the default configuration...
simplified build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.compose)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.compose)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
}

.
.
.

commonMain.dependencies {
    .
    .
    .

        implementation(project.dependencies.platform(libs.koin.bom))
        implementation(libs.koin.core)
        implementation(libs.koin.core.coroutines)
        implementation(project.dependencies.platform(libs.koin.annotations.bom))
        implementation(libs.koin.annotations)
        implementation(libs.koin.compose)
        implementation(libs.koin.compose.viewmodel)
    .
    .
    .
}

ksp {
    arg("USE_COMPOSE_VIEWMODEL","true")
}

dependencies {
    add("kspCommonMainMetadata", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
    // Platform specific compilation targets
    add("kspAndroid", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
    add("kspIosX64", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
    add("kspIosArm64", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
    add("kspIosSimulatorArm64", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
    add("kspDesktop", libs.koin.ksp.compiler)
}


did you find a solution? doc seems the same but i'm not sure whether they actually updated it. for me it's the same and i'm stuck with kotlin 1.9 because of that.

I have the same issue and can't figure out how to make it work, so I am just creating  all the dependencies in the ios module manually.

As of today's date, It says in the documentation that 2.0.0 isn't supported yet

Latest KSP compatible version: 1.9.24-1.0.20

Source: Koin Annotations Documentation
